# How to extract data from nested Json in Jmeter using Json Extractor

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

{"data": {"callOrders": [{
"promotionId": null,
"Promotion": null,
"Lines":     [
{
"id": 5105808,
"quantity": 10,
"skuId": 769,
"callId": 494285,
"skuBatchId": 733,
"amountDetails":             {
"rate": 197.53,
"grossAmount": 2232.089,
"netAmount": 2232.089,
"taxAmount": 256.789,
"taxableAmount": 1975.3,
"subTotal": 1975.3,
"billDiscount": 0,
"tradeDiscount": 0,
"discountAmount": 0,
"promotionDiscount": 0,
"topUpDiscount": 0,
"__typename": "AmountDetail"
},
"rateDetails":             {
"rlp": 197.53,
"rlpWithVat": 223.2089,
"netPrice": 197.53,
"netPriceWithVat": 223.2089,
"__typename": "RateDetail"
},
"SKU":             {
"id": 769,
"title": "H&S 2in1 Active Protect 180 ml x 24 [82302894]",
"__typename": "SKU"
},
"SKUBatch":             {
"priceDetails":                 {
"rlp": 197.53,
"dlp": 186.35,
"vatPercentage": 0.13,
"mrpSrp": 250,
"mrpStatus": true,
"__typename": "SKUPrice"
},
"batchDetails":                 {
"batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
"__typename": "SKUBatch"
},
"usageDate":                 {
"manufacture": "0000-00-00",
"expiry": "0000-00-00",
"__typename": "SKUUsage"
},
"updatedAt": "2019-11-05",
"active": true,
"__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
},
"Promotion":             {
"id": null,
"title": null,
"type": null,
"scope": null,
"criteria": null,
"__typename": "Promotion"
},
"promotionId": null,
"distributorId": 16,
"__typename": "Line",
"inStock": "INSTOCK",
"freeSku": false,
"focusedSku": false
},
{
"id": 5105809,
"quantity": 50,
"skuId": 95,
"callId": 494285,
"skuBatchId": 111,
"amountDetails":             {
"rate": 56.89,
"grossAmount": 3214.2852,
"netAmount": 3214.285,
"taxAmount": 369.785,
"taxableAmount": 2844.5,
"subTotal": 2844.5,
"billDiscount": 0,
"tradeDiscount": 0,
"discountAmount": 0,
"promotionDiscount": 0,
"topUpDiscount": 0,
"__typename": "AmountDetail"
},
"rateDetails":             {
"rlp": 56.89,
"rlpWithVat": 64.2857,
"netPrice": 56.89,
"netPriceWithVat": 64.2857,
"__typename": "RateDetail"
},
"SKU":             {
"id": 95,
"title": "Whisper Choice 6s x 96 [82252488]",
"__typename": "SKU"
},
"SKUBatch":             {
"priceDetails":                 {
"rlp": 56.89,
"dlp": 53.67,
"vatPercentage": 0.13,
"mrpSrp": 72,
"mrpStatus": true,
"__typename": "SKUPrice"
},
"batchDetails":                 {
"batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
"__typename": "SKUBatch"
},
"usageDate":                 {
"manufacture": "0000-00-00",
"expiry": "0000-00-00",
"__typename": "SKUUsage"
},
"updatedAt": "2016-08-15",
"active": true,
"__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
},
"Promotion":             {
"id": null,
"title": null,
"type": null,
"scope": null,
"criteria": null,
"__typename": "Promotion"
},
"promotionId": null,
"distributorId": 16,
"__typename": "Line",
"inStock": "INSTOCK",
"freeSku": false,
"focusedSku": false
},
{
"id": 5105810,
"quantity": 10,
"skuId": 82,
"callId": 494285,
"skuBatchId": 551,
"amountDetails":             {
"rate": 281.88,
"grossAmount": 3185.244,
"netAmount": 3185.244,
"taxAmount": 366.444,
"taxableAmount": 2818.8,
"subTotal": 2818.8,
"billDiscount": 0,
"tradeDiscount": 0,
"discountAmount": 0,
"promotionDiscount": 0,
"topUpDiscount": 0,
"__typename": "AmountDetail"
},
"rateDetails":             {
"rlp": 281.88,
"rlpWithVat": 318.5244,
"netPrice": 281.88,
"netPriceWithVat": 318.5244,
"__typename": "RateDetail"
},
"SKU":             {
"id": 82,
"title": "Ariel Oxyblu 1 kg x 24 [82250306]",
"__typename": "SKU"
},
"SKUBatch":             {
"priceDetails":                 {
"rlp": 281.88,
"dlp": 268.45,
"vatPercentage": 0.13,
"mrpSrp": 344,
"mrpStatus": true,
"__typename": "SKUPrice"
},
"batchDetails":                 {
"batchNumber": "DEFAULT_BATCH",
"__typename": "SKUBatch"
},
"usageDate":                 {
"manufacture": "0000-00-00",
"expiry": "0000-00-00",
"__typename": "SKUUsage"
},
"updatedAt": "2018-01-31",
"active": true,
"__typename": "SKUBatchRate"
},
"Promotion":             {
"id": null,
"title": null,
"type": null,
"scope": null,
"criteria": null,
"__typename": "Promotion"
},
"promotionId": null,
"distributorId": 16,
"__typename": "Line",
"inStock": "INSTOCK",
"freeSku": false,
"focusedSku": false
}
],
"__typename": "PromotionOrder"
}]}}

Using $..Lines..id I am getting  this
[
5105808,
769,
null,
5105809,
95,
null,
5105810,
82,
null
]

But I want to get value [ 5105808, 5105809, 5105810] only. What should be the way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `..` which is a [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) which means that you're looking for all `id` attribute values no matter where they're located in the JSON.

If you want to get only `id` of the attributes which are direct children of the `Lines` object - you need to amend your query to look like: `$..Lines[*].id`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

> $..[?(@.skuId)].id

This gets elements that have the skuId attribute and extracts the id attribute.

Comment: I want to learn more to get data from json. Where can I learn or find more json path expressions? Thanks